# Accidently deleted folder using Unlocker, how to restore it?

Tags: windows-xp, data-recovery

My bad! I accidently restore an important folder with [Unlocker](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Unlocker-Download-68439.html) today.

I can see it in Recycle Bin but I can't restore it. It reports

> Error Copying File or Folder: Access is denied. Make sure the disk is not full or write-protected and that the file is not currently in use.

**That folder is very important**. It contains some Virtual machine I'm studying. I can't lose it. Any help will be appreciated very very much.

I'm using Windows XP SP3.

Comment: Can you use a Linux Live CD and access the Recycle Bin that way?

Comment: I'm using Windows and doesn't install Linux. :(

Comment: No I mean, for example [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org/main/Overview%20and%20Getting%20Started.htm). Burn it to a CD and pop it in the drive. You can run Linux, access your hard disk and copy the file from the recycle bin somewhere else. Before you do that, have you tried rebooting or uninstalling unlocker?

Comment: Too late, after some actions, I lost my data in recycle bin. :(
I am going to recover it using Hirren Boot CD. Thank you.